# Does this Sobolev-space like construction have a name?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Take $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ arbitrary then define as $X$ the closure of $C^1(\Omega) \cap W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ w.r.t. the norm $f \mapsto \left\lVert f \right\rVert_{\infty} + \left\lVert \nabla f \right\rVert_{1}.$ The beauty of this space is that it sort of compensates the lack of continuity of $W^{1,1}$ functions in higher dimensions. But I did not find a reference to this space anywhere. In fact, this space would be $C_0(\Omega) \cap W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ if I see it correctly where $C_0(\Omega)$ is the space of cont. functions with limit zero at infinity.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is a "nice" set (with Lipschitz boundary for example), isn't this just $W^{1,1}\cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$?

Comment: @Paul-Benjamin no, functions in this space are not necessarily continuous, in the construction above they are.

Comment: This is all functions that satisfy the fundamental theorem in the sense that $f(x)=f(a)+\int_0^x V(t)\, dt$, for some (vector field) $V\in L^1$. In fact, this condition looks like a reasonable generalization of AC to higher dimensions.